# AngularJS reload page does not work

Tags: angularjs, reload

I need to refresh a list after an update and I've tried all the solutions and none worked for me, I'm a newbie to Angular.

My code is:

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="customersCrtl">
<div class="container">
<br/>
<blockquote><h4>Registro de Ingreso</h4></blockquote>
<br/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">Limite de Pagina:
        <select ng-model="entryLimit" class="form-control">
            <option>10</option>
            <option>50</option>
            <option>100</option>
            <option>250</option>
            <option>500</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Buscar Por:
        <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="filter()" placeholder="Carnet de Identidad" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h5>Listados {{ filtered.length }} de {{ totalItems}} Clientes registrados</h5>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <th>ID Cliente&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Nombre&nbsp;</th>
        <th>eMail&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Detalles&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Marcar Ingreso&nbsp;</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
                <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.email}}</td>
                <td>{{data.extras}}</td>
                <td><a ng-click="updateCliente(data.id)" class="pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems == 0">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4>No customers found</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">    
        <div pagination="" page="currentPage" on-select-page="setPage(page)" boundary-links="true" total-items="filteredItems" items-per-page="entryLimit" class="pagination-small" previous-text="&laquo;" next-text="&raquo;"></div>


    </div>
</div>
```

and my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.filter('startFrom', function() {
return function(input, start) {
    if(input) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
    return [];
}
});
app.controller('customersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
$http.get('ajax/getCustomers.php').success(function(data){
    $scope.list = data;
    $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
    $scope.entryLimit = 5; //max no of items to display in a page
    $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
});
$scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
};
$scope.filter = function() {
    $timeout(function() { 
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
    }, 10);
};
$scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
    $scope.predicate = predicate;
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
};
$scope.reload = function() {
    location.reload(); 
}; 
$scope.updateCliente = function (cliente) {
if(confirm("Confirma el ingreso?")){
$http.post("ajax/updateCliente.php?idCliente="+cliente).success(function(data){
    reload();
  });
 }
};

});
```

On the success event of the post, I need to reload. The DB is updated, so the result of the http.post must be a Success.

I have also tried with `$window.location.reload();` instead of `location.reload();` and it did not work.

Comment: Why do you want to reload? Also, your `reload()` should be `$scope.reload()` and you should not use the `$http` `success` method as it has long been deprecated. Use `then` instead of `success`.

Comment: Dear Aluan, basically the idea of the webpage is to display a list of customers and a button related to each, when pressed the button display a Confirm and executes a query in updateCliente.php that makes an update on the data of that client, after that, the client is still in the list but, based on the query that builds the table, it must be removed, if I press F5 the client is no more show and the database is all ok...

Comment: You should prefer to update the list on the client if the request succeeds instead of reloading the page, that is the point of SPAs

Comment: Other way to see is.. I need to call again $http.get('ajax/getCustomers.php') but, as this is a template that im using to learn.. i dont know exatcly how...

Comment: I added an answer showing how to get the data again. It also demonstrates some practices you really should follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget your reload function is in scope so call it via $scope.

Replace

```
reload();
```

By

```
$scope.reload();
```

Comment: It works!!! :D :D :D thank you so much, if you have any idea about how can i write the app.js to call $http.get('ajax/getCustomers.php') again, it will be really great :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading the page, fetch the data again

**Note:** I am using `then` not `success` as the latter is deprecated, so observe the difference in how data is accessed)

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  app.controller({CustomersController});

  CustomersController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout'];
  function CustomersController($scope, $http, $timeout) {

    getData(); // defined below

    function getData() {
      $http.get('ajax/getCustomers.php').then(function (response) {
        $scope.list = response.data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 5; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
      });
    }

    $scope.updateCliente = function (cliente) {
      if(confirm("Confirma el ingreso?")) {
        // Below, we pass `getData` as the function that will be called when the 
        // http request completes successfully. This will refresh the data on `$scope`
        $http.post("ajax/updateCliente.php?idCliente=" + cliente).then(getData);
      }
    };
  }

}());
```